# How to stop service on home key press

Tags: android, media-player, android-service

I am implementing following service to play sound. This sound stop when someone press on any menu button. But If I press home key of device sound still playing. I am adding this code

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
stopService(objIntent);
}
```

in my activity class. But still sound not stop. why onPause method is not working?

Service code-

```
public class PlayAudio extends Service{
private static final String LOGCAT = null;
MediaPlayer objPlayer;

public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Service Started!");
objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
objPlayer.start();
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
if(objPlayer.isLooping() != true){
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
}
return 1;
}

public void onStop(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}

public void onPause(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
public void onDestroy(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent objIndent) {
return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Im not sure how services work fully, but it looks like you are calling `stopService` on a new instance of the service? Should you not be doing this on your existing service..

Answer (score 0):

you can stop service on home key press..try this

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        {
         objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
         stopService(objIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can we listen for keyevents in Service?

Comment: yes but not through this approach..you can listen it through broadcast receiver...but i think that is not the case here...

Answer (score 0):

write one `Thread` in `Service` which continuosly checks for running tasks and stop the `Service` if top task's top activity package name is equal to the package name of launcher app...

```
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            final List<ResolveInfo> activities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), 0);
            final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            while(true) {
                String packageName = activityManager.getRunningTasks(5).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
                if(activities.contains(packageName)) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500); // wait for half second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            stopSelf();
        };
    }.start();
```